# Error binding reference to array passed to function (c++)

Tags: c++

I'm using `MinGW64` with `eclipse`, language is `C++` as stated above.

I have the following code:

```
double * my_Function (my_Class I1, my_Class I2, double return_vector[3])
{
    double test[3];
    double (&rtest)[3]=test;
    double (&description_vector)[3] = return_vector;

    // some more code
    return (description_vector);
}
```

Binding rtest to test works fine, here the compiler tells me `warning: unused variable`, that is to be expected, as it's not used anywhere in the code I just wanted to find out if it works in principle.

However binding `description_vector` to `return_vector` results in the following error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'double (&)[3]' from expression of type 'double*'
```

Why? Why is binding rtest to test legal but not the binding of `description_vector` to `return_vector`?

So you may ask "But why binding the reference `description_vector` to `return_vector`? Simply use `return_vector` in your return statement - it's the same after all."

I want to confer information to the reader of the code (basically me when I'll look at it in the future). This way you see that you have to pass a vector to the function for the purpose of returning it's calculation.
You see that `description_vector` is an alias for `return_vector` and by the name of `description_vector` you can see what it is supposed to hold.

Comment: BTW, arrays are evil, pointers are evil ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function it decays to a pointer to the first element and you can't bind it to a reference to an array. You should either pass a reference to an array as a parameter or make your life easier by using vectors (and iterators).

Comment: Thank you very much. I've changed it to double *(&description_vector) = return_vector; and my compiler stopped complaining.

Comment: But this would work, wouldn't it? If I'm not mistaken, what happens is: I'll create an array before calling the function. I'll pass a pointer to the first element of this array to the function. Inside the function I bind a reference to this pointer. The function does it's calculations and the result is given to the reference which actually is the same as the pointer and thus the calculated result is put inside the array I created earlier, then the pointer to this array is returned. And this is what would happen in any case even without binding an alias to return_vector.

Comment: At that point it would be simpler to just use a plain pointer to double. Personally I'd pass a vector or an output iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the two array signatures look alike, the compiler will actually pass the return_array as a double* unlike the test array which is a double[3]. Basically they are different types. Passing arrays like this is shorthand for double*.

Answer (score 0):

```
double * my_Function (my_Class I1, my_Class I2, double return_vector[3])
//                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The underlined syntax used in a function declaration means the same as `double*`. The bound is happily ignored by the compiler and is hardly more than a comment telling, say, the size the array that `return_vector` is supposed to point at.

Arrays are not pointers, they *decay* to pointers when passed to functions. This is the reason binding `test` works, as it is a proper array.

If you want to stick with references inside the function, you'll need to take a reference as a parameter, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is actually identical to:

```
double * my_Function (my_Class I1, my_Class I2, double *return_vector)
```

This is an historical quirk of the syntax for function formal parameter lists.

Also, arrays cannot be passed by value in C++ (there are no array-type rvalues).